# Equivariant $K$-theory and proper actions of discrete groups

Tags: stable-homotopy, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy, equivariant

The work of Lück and Oliver describes the generalization of equivariant $K$-theory to infinite discrete groups. When $X$ is a finite proper $G$-CW complex, there exist Bott isomorphisms $K^n_G(X)\cong K^{n+2}_G(X)$. My question is:
When $X$ is a point, the action of the infinite discrete $G$ is not proper, then how does one compute the coefficient ring $K^\ast_G(pt.)$ as it is not known whether Bott periodicity still applies?